# Application_AuthenticateRequest fires to late

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, forms-authentication

When I create my formsauthenticationticket the Application_AuthenticateRequest (in global.asax) is fired not immediatly. When I check user.isrole it's empty. But later on when I try another action the Application_AuthenticateRequest is fired, and the roles of the user are set.

Login function:

```
      if (loggedIn)
            {
                ViewBag.loginFailed = 1;
                string roles = "Administrator";
                CreateTicket(pharmacist.ID.ToString(), roles);
                LoginRedirect();
            }
```

Methods:

```
    [Authorize(Roles = "Administrator, User")]
    private void CreateTicket(string id, string role)
    {

        var ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
                version: 1,
                name: id,
                issueDate: DateTime.Now,
                expiration: DateTime.Now.AddHours(1),
                isPersistent: false,
                userData: role);

        var encryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
        var cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encryptedTicket);
        HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
    }

   [Authorize(Roles = "Administrator, User")]
    private ActionResult LoginRedirect() {
        if (User.IsInRole("Administrator"))
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Pharmacist");
        }
        else if (User.IsInRole("User"))
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Patient");
        }
        else {
            return RedirectToAction("Logout", "Authentication");
        }
    }
```

Application_AuthenticateRequest

```
  protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.User != null)
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity is FormsIdentity)
                {
                    FormsIdentity id =
                        (FormsIdentity)HttpContext.Current.User.Identity;
                    FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = id.Ticket;

                    // Get the stored user-data, in this case, our roles
                    string userData = ticket.UserData;
                    string[] roles = userData.Split(',');
                    HttpContext.Current.User = new GenericPrincipal(id, roles);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Application_AuthenticateRequest*** is only called when you request a new resource.

In your case, you are still in the request which creates ***FormsAuthenticationTicket***. As the result, ***Principal object*** hasn't been assigned to the current thread yet.

***If you want to retrieve IPrincipal from the current thread, you will need to assign it explicitly.***

```
var encryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
var cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encryptedTicket);
// You need this two lines.
HttpContext.Current.User = new GenericPrincipal(id, roles); 
Thread.CurrentPrincipal = HttpContext.Current.User;
....
```

Also make sure you have those two line inside ***Application_AuthenticateRequest***.

```
protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   ...
   HttpContext.Current.User = new GenericPrincipal(id, roles);
   Thread.CurrentPrincipal = HttpContext.Current.User; <-- Do not forget this.
   ...
}
```

---

***FYI***: You do not need **AuthorizeAttribute** on private method. You only want it on Controller or Action Methods.

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator, User")] <-- This is not needed.
private void CreateTicket(string id, string role)
{
   ...
}
```